# How can I make options apply to a GUI in AHK?

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey, always-on-top

I'm trying to make a simple script that shows and hides a small GUI over the "close" button on a window (in the top right of the screen). For some reason, the GUI is not applying any of the options I added (or subtracted). The options I want to apply are `+LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption`.

I have tried rearranging the code, named GUIs, and pausing the other script that I normally use.

Here is the entire script:

```
ShowWindow := false

#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

Gui New, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption, Protect
    Winset, TransColor, F0F0F0 175

#+^CapsLock::
    ShowWindow:=!ShowWindow
    If (ShowWindow) {
        Gui Show, x1226 y0 w140 h10 NA Restore, Protect
    } Else {
        Gui Hide
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetBatchLines -1

#+^CapsLock::
    ShowWindow  :=  !ShowWindow
    Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
    Winset, TransColor, F0F0F0 175

    Gui, Add, Button, , Button

    Gui,% ShowWindow ? "Show" : "Destroy",% ShowWindow ? "x1226 y0 w140 h50" : "",% ShowWindow ? "Protect" : ""

Return
```

Comment: It works - But can you explain how the code works? I want to know so I can learn why it wasn't working

Comment: [This topic](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=4113) could clarify your doubts about why your code didn't work and why I personally avoid using Gui New in my scripts.

Comment: In my code example, i'm essentially creating and destroying the GUI using a ternary operator for displaying or destroying the GUI.